# How do I access the layers of a loaded multi_gpu model in Keras?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer, tf.keras

I have a deep learning model whose layers I'd like to expose ala [this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-your-convolution-network-with-visualizations-a4883441533b).  I want to visualize the activations on a test image.  However, I train using multiple gpus and save the best checkpoint for training.  So, when I hit model.summary() on a loaded model, instead of the traditional architecture output, I get this, which I'm unable to use:

```
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_2 (InputLayer)            (None, 256, 256, 3)  0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lambda_1 (Lambda)               (None, 256, 256, 3)  0           input_2[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lambda_2 (Lambda)               (None, 256, 256, 3)  0           input_2[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lambda_3 (Lambda)               (None, 256, 256, 3)  0           input_2[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lambda_4 (Lambda)               (None, 256, 256, 3)  0           input_2[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lambda_5 (Lambda)               (None, 256, 256, 3)  0           input_2[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lambda_6 (Lambda)               (None, 256, 256, 3)  0           input_2[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lambda_7 (Lambda)               (None, 256, 256, 3)  0           input_2[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lambda_8 (Lambda)               (None, 256, 256, 3)  0           input_2[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
model_2 (Model)                 (None, 256, 256, 1)  31032837    lambda_1[0][0]                   
                                                                 lambda_2[0][0]                   
                                                                 lambda_3[0][0]                   
                                                                 lambda_4[0][0]                   
                                                                 lambda_5[0][0]                   
                                                                 lambda_6[0][0]                   
                                                                 lambda_7[0][0]                   
                                                                 lambda_8[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_48 (Concatenate)         (None, 256, 256, 1)  0           model_2[1][0]                    
                                                                 model_2[2][0]                    
                                                                 model_2[3][0]                    
                                                                 model_2[4][0]                    
                                                                 model_2[5][0]                    
                                                                 model_2[6][0]                    
                                                                 model_2[7][0]                    
                                                                 model_2[8][0]                    
==================================================================================================
Total params: 31,032,837
Trainable params: 31,032,837
Non-trainable params: 0
```

How do I retrieve/expose the weights and architecture of a saved multi gpu model?  Is there a way to convert it "back to normal," so to speak?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After loading model either with `model = load_model('model.h5')` or  `model.load_weights(load_path)`, just do this

```
single_model = model.layers[-2]
```

Then you can access desired layers with `model.layers[i]` or through iterating

```
for layer in model.layers:
    #do smth
```

Comment: Oh, sweet!  That's perfect.  Thank you!